# Text adventure game-python

Tags: python

I am new with coding. I have started this coding and it keeps giving me an error when I run the code. Can you tell me what is wrong with my code?

```
import time
import random

response = []
decision_list = ["1", "2"]
print(random.choice(decision_list))


def print_pause(message_to_print):
    print(message_to_print)
    time.sleep(1)


def valid_input(prompt, option1, option2):
    while True:
        response = input(prompt).lower()
        if 1 == response:
            break
        elif 2 == response:
            break
    return response


def intro():
    print_pause("You find yourself driving down a long road alone to a cabin.")
    print_pause("You have heard on the radio that it is a bear on the loose.")
    print_pause("All of a sudden your car slows down by the dark woods.")
    print_pause("You become terrified, but you see a house nearby for help.")
    print_pause("You come closer to the house, it is a big shed to the left.")
    print_pause("In your pocket, you have a pocketknife.")


def decision():
    response = valid_input("Enter 1 to knock on the door of the house."
                           "Enter 2 to walk into the shed."
                           "What is you decision?"
                           "Please enter 1 or 2.")
    if "1" in response:
        print_pause("You have arrived to the door of the house.")
        print_pause("Before knocking, the door starts to creek open.")
        print_pause("The bear is standing in the doorway.")
        print_pause("The bear attacks.")
        print_pause("With your pocket knife, you cannot handle the bear.")

    elif "2" in response:
        print_pause("You walk towards the shed.")
        print_pause("You look around and you saw a gun.")
        print_pause("Next to the gun are bullets.")
        print_pause("You have a weapon for protection besides your pocketknife.")
        print_pause("You walk back to the house.")
        play_again()


def action():
    response = valid_input("Would you like to 1 fight or 2 run away?"
                           " Please enter 1 or 2.")
    if "1" in response:
        print_pause("The bear attacks and you have taken out the gun.")
        print_pause("You begin to shoot the bear.")
        print_pause("You have defeated the bear!!")
    elif "2" in response:
        print_pause(" You run back to your car where it is safe.")
    elif "1" in response:
        print_pause("You begin fighting back.")
        print_pause("The pocketknife is not helpful.")
        print_pause("The bear had defeated you!!")


def play_again():
    response = valid_input("Would you like to play again?"
                           "Please say 'yes' or 'no'.\n",
                           "yes", "no")
    if "yes" == response:
        print_pause("Great! Restarting game.")
        play_drive()
    elif "no" == response:
        print_pause("Thanks for playing!! Goodbye!")
        exit(0)


def play_drive():
    intro()
    decision()
    action()
    play_drive()
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: I don't get an error when I run your code, it just prints "2" and exits. You may want to call your functions, currently you only define them.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/mac/drive.py", line 82, in <module>
    play_drive()
  File "/Users/mac/drive.py", line 79, in play_drive
    decision()
  File "/Users/mac/drive.py", line 34, in decision
    response = valid_input("Enter 1 to knock", "Enter 2 to walk in the shed,"
TypeError: valid_input() missing 1 required positional argument: 'option2'

Comment: I just posted the error.

Comment: Please don't add answers or comments to clarify, [edit] your question instead. Answers are only for answers. Comments are hard to read, especially with code, and they are shown in order of votes, not chronologically. See also [ask].

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the first line of the function decision. There you call the function valid_input with only one argument. I'm not sure if you need it but you separate the different arguments by a coma. Hope I helped you:)

Comment: Hello, I added the comas and it gave me an error.File "/Users/mac/drive.py", line 79, in <module>
    play_drive()
  File "/Users/mac/drive.py", line 76, in play_drive
    decision()
  File "/Users/mac/drive.py", line 31, in decision
    response = valid_input("Enter 1 to knock", "Enter 2 to walk in the shed,"
TypeError: valid_input() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Answer (score 0):

You didnt mention what is your error, but I can point out a few things that will not work.

You defined `valid_input(prompt, option1, option2)`, which means three parameters are expected. But you just pass a text everytime you invoke `valid_input()` so that will produce an error. But later in the code you never use `option1` and `option2` for anythin, since you have hardcode `1` and `2` in the `if..elif`. Also keep in mind that input will capture the value as string, and then you compare it with two integers. So better:

```
def valid_input(prompt, option1 = "1", option2 = "2"):
    while True:
        response = input(prompt).lower()
        if option1 == response or option2 == response:
            return response

response = valid_input("Enter 1 to knock on the door of the house."
    "Enter 2 to walk into the shed."    
    "What is you decision?"
    "Please enter 1 or 2.")
```

Update: Since you try to invoke the same function sometimes passing the options as "yes"/"no" and sometimes you want to compare with "1" and "2", what you can do is to keep "1" and "2" as default, and those values will be ignored in case you invoke `valid_input` with "yes" and "no"

Comment: (The error)Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/mac/drive.py", line 82, in <module>
    play_drive()
  File "/Users/mac/drive.py", line 79, in play_drive
    decision()
  File "/Users/mac/drive.py", line 34, in decision
    response = valid_input("Enter 1 to knock", "Enter 2 to walk in the shed,"
TypeError: valid_input() missing 1 required positional argument: 'option2'

Comment: @KimikaStevenson   Yeah, what I was thinking, you need to remove parameters that I don't need in your `valid_input`. Replace it with the code I suggested

Comment: File "/Users/mac/drive.py", line 79, in <module>
    play_drive()
  File "/Users/mac/drive.py", line 76, in play_drive
    decision()
  File "/Users/mac/drive.py", line 31, in decision
    response = valid_input("Enter 1 to knock", "Enter 2 to walk in the shed,"
TypeError: valid_input() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Comment: @KimikaStevenson Updated. Try now

Comment: def valid_input(prompt):
    while True:
        response = int(input(prompt))
        if 1 == response or 2 == response:
            return response
def intro():
    print_pause("You find yourself driving down a long road alone to a cabin.")
    print_pause("You have heard on the radio that it is a bear on the loose.")
    print_pause("All of a sudden your car slows down by the dark woods.")
    print_pause("You become terrified, but you see a house nearby for help.")

Comment: @KimikaStevenson but try with the new version of the code, with the option1 and option2 back in place

Comment: def valid_input(prompt):
    while True:
        response = int(input(prompt))
        if 1 == response or 2 == response:
            return response

Comment: @KimikaStevenson please check again, it looks like this: def valid_input(prompt, option1 = "1", option2 = "2"):
    while True:
        response = input(prompt)
        if option1 == response or option2 == response:
            return response

Comment: Enter 1 to knock1
Enter 1 to knock1
Enter 1 to knock1
Enter 1 to knock....

Comment: It was showing this --Enter 1 to knock1
Enter 1 to knock1
Enter 1 to knock1
Enter 1 to knock

Comment: @KimikaStevenson how are you invoking valid_input()? what parameters are you passing?

Comment: def valid_input(prompt, option1 = "1", option2 = "2"):
    while True:
        response = input(prompt).lower()
        if option1 == response or option2 == response:
            return response

Comment: I've just posted.

Comment: That is how you define it, I mean how you call it. Like valid_input("some message") or something similar.